# Is there any way for me to redirect to this new window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming so I would like ask is there any way to redirect to this window. I have tried searching on youtube and google but it did not tell me anything that could be of use.
I have a login window that I want to be redirected to this window after a successful login.

```
class Admin:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Covid 19 Admin Panel")
        self.root.geometry("1510x780+0+0")

         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    ob = Admin(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should probably make the different "windows" as frames and then switch between them (or destroy one and populate `root` with the other). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) for more.

Comment: Ahh I've tried that but it just tells me admin is not defined and I changed it by doing class  admin (tk.frame):

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("480x480");
    win.title("Title");

    def login_redirect():
        win.destroy()
        login_page()

    login = Button(win, text="login", command=login_redirect)
    login.place(x=40,y=40)

    win.mainloop()

def login_page():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("480x480");
    win.title("Covid 19 Admin Panel")

main()
```